# Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\Sales", "DateTime" given

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Regardless of date format used (Symfony 3.3.14), the error in title appears on submitting a form with the following field definition:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
...

    $builder
        ->add('sales', DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => false,
            'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
            'format' => 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            ])
```

and with the associated javascript

```
$('.js-datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
});
```

as called in the template with

```
{{ form_row(form.sales) }}
...
    {%  block javascripts %}
        {{ parent() }}
        <script src="/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/tickets.js"></script>
    {%  endblock javascripts %}
```

Comment: Is perhaps `$sales` in your entity defined as relationship between your entity itself and `AppBundle\Entity\Sales` entity?

Comment: Your comment came just as I realized that.  Post it as an answer and I'll accept it and delete mine.

Comment: Alright, you can accept yours :)

Comment: You're too kind.  Sure you won't? I don't mind.

Comment: Sure, no problem, but thank you for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOH!

The entity definition that included the sales field some how got

```
public function setSales(Sales $sales)
{
    $this->sales = $sales;

    return $this;
}
```

when it should have been

```
public function setSales($sales)
{
    $this->sales = $sales;

    return $this;
}
```